# Validation error when selecting date greater than 12

Tags: datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my mvc4 application if i select date greater than 12,am getting error "Date is not valid".
It works good for date less than 12..The format obtained while selecting date in datepicker is 'mm/dd/yyyy'.
My model is:-

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date Of Birth is required")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
        public DateTime? DOB{ get; set; }
```

Script for datepicker is:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $('.datepicker').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
            $(this).datepicker();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Please tell a solution for this..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any magic that would pass the date format from data annotations of your model into the jQueryUI date picker.  You have to do that explicitly:

```
$(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
```

Reference [this documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Comment: same problem for me also i too tried with above solution but still same problem @ Matt Johnson